# How to fetch the link that is outside the href tag?

Tags: java, html, netbeans, web-scraping

```
private static final Pattern ptninhref =Pattern.compile(
            "(?:.*\\<[aA][^\\>]*(?i)href(?-i)=\\\"[^\\\"]*)([^\\\"]*)");

    public static List<String> captureValuesinhref(String largeText){
        Matcher mtchinhref = ptninhref.matcher(largeText);
        List<String> inHREF = new ArrayList<>();
        while(mtchinhref.find()){
           inHREF.add(mtchinhref.group());
```

How to fetch only  `"link is given "`? 
 When i am using `(?:.*\<[aA][^\>]*(?i)href(?-i)=\"[^\"]*)([^\"]*)(?:[^\"]*\".*\</[aA]\>.*)` this regular expression code, it gives me output like: `<a href="link is given here">link is given here</a>`. 
 
But required output only: `"link is given here"` 
I have required the link which is outside the href tag.

There are two link : 
1 is inside the href tag. 
2 is outside the href tag that is shown in the browser. 
I have required the 2nd link only. 
How to fetch that using java in netbeans?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, would you mind to elaborate? Maybe add some code of what you tried so far.

Comment: did you undrstd what i want to ask?

Comment: No, i don't understand your problem.

Comment: i want to fetch an URL that is outside the href tag

Comment: <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>   <-- which part do you want to fetch? and in what is it stored?  String?  Always try to ask your question in a way that some one outsider can understand it. like i'm a 11 year old.

Comment: i want to fetch this :Visit W3Schools.com! But it also contains an URL(Link).. when i tried to fetch it using regular expression((?:.\<[aA][^>](?i)href(?-i)=\"[^\"])([^\"])(?:[^\"]\".\.*)) using java it gives me the whole part means <a href="w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a> But i have required only Visit W3Schools.com which is also an URL(link)

Comment: On the result, do another reg express, something like:  ([>])(\\?.)*?([<])    (this still includes the '>' '<')

Comment: I have tried this.It is not working.can you please give me your email id? i will send my code .It is not possible to send it here.If possible..please..it is urgent

Comment: You can add the code here.. it is even prefered to post code here. use the curly bracket icon in the editor to format your text

Comment: Okk... I have done that.Thanks for that.I have tried by removing everything from the opening anchor tag till the closing anchor tag. But still not working..What i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class RegexExample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String href= "<a href=\"w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>";
        String regexOr = "(?<=[>])(\\\\?.)*?(?=[<])";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexOr);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(href);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String enrichedValue = matcher.group();
            System.out.print(enrichedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This will print:

> Visit W3Schools.com!

*Keep in mind \ becomes \\ in java, it needs to be escaped*

Full example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexExample {
    private static final Pattern ptninhref;
    static{
        ptninhref = Pattern.compile("(?<=[>])(\\\\?.)*?(?=[<])");
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String href= "<a href=\"paypal.com/signin/\">https://www.paypa1.com/signin/</a>";
        List<String> results = captureValuesinhref(href);
        for(String result:results){
            System.out.print(result);
        }
    }

    public static List<String> captureValuesinhref(String largeText){
        Matcher mtchinhref = ptninhref.matcher(largeText);
        List<String> inHREF = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(mtchinhref.find()){
           inHREF.add(mtchinhref.group());
        }
        return inHREF;
    }
}
```

prints:

> https://www.paypa1.com/signin/

Comment: it only gives run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds) It was working only when there is Some text(Strings) outside the tag {<a href=\"w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>} means here "Visit W3Schools.com! " is a strings .So it gives the output But insted of that when there is link(URL) like {http://example.com }then it is not working

Comment: Have you tried the "public class RegexExample { ....}   "?  It should print : "Visit W3Schools.com!", as you want. Give an example of how the String largeText looks like?

Comment: I have tried..String href= "<a href=\"w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>"; Instead of this take this one as  a input String href= "<a href="https://www.paypal.com/signin/">https://www.paypa1.com/signin/</a> FOr this it was not working

Comment: How to fetch URL only that is inside the tag with "<a href= "   Only URL i have required